# How to disable proxy for CloudFlare?

Tags: node.js, server, proxy, dns, cloudflare

I changed my domain's nameserver to CloudFalre yesterday. But I'm confuse about Caching system of CloudFlare.

My server is Node.js based server and even client request same url, sometimes server response with different contents.

As I found on internet, CloudFlare uses cache for fast browsing. It saves the content of server in their cache server and when client request same resource to server, CloudFlare returns resource to client without connecting with original server.

So if server's resource become different, CloudFlare will return old resource, is it right?

I setted A record for some domain and it become a "Proxying Mode". I cannot change it to gray connection.

Should I pay for do it? or is there a way to change this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare should not cache text/html, application/json types of responses. Static javascript files and images may be cached. [Here is an article about what will be cached by default](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Understanding-Cloudflare-s-CDN).

There should be no reason that you cannot change the "orange cloud" proxied mode to "grey cloud" DNS by clicking the icon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know it's possible to switch it by just clicking icon. Thanks.